# can we reopen Selected images using Photo Picker android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using the Photo Picker to select multiple pictures. When I want to reopen selected images, how can I achieve this using the Photo Picker?

launching on the button click

```
    pickMultipleMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.
         PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
```

here get response

```
   pickMultipleMedia = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(
            30
        )
    ) { uris ->
        if (uris.isNotEmpty()) {

            binding.root.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            attachmentIdsList = ArrayList<String>()
            urisList.clear()
            urisList.addAll(uris)

            multipleImages.notifyDataSetChanged()

            findImageSize(uris)
        } else {
            findNavController().popBackStack()
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by reopening?

Comment: Yes, i was about to ask the same ;-) I dont see they are opened once. Further you did not tell the problem you encountered doing so.

Comment: After selecting images and obtaining the results as a URI list, there may be a situation where I want to add more images. To achieve this, I would like the photo picker to display the images that I have already selected when I open again it, so that I can add new images to the existing list.

Comment: When you open it again, does the uri value appear empty?

Comment: once I launch the photo picker and get the list of Uris I want to open the images,that I have selected already and show them as selected in the view

Comment: Isn't it selected when you open it again?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#device-availability This document serves as a reference that I have followed.

Comment: `would like the photo picker to display the images that I have already selected when I open again it, ` Well that is not possible.

Comment: Have you tried to make a database for that? Let's say you selected some images, and then put them in the database.

Comment: My requirement is to open a view of the photo picker with pre-selected images I have a list of URIs @Ticherhaz FreePalestine
 I follow the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker